# Show different text based on OS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show different text based on the OS the user is using. I have the code on CSS browser selector (from here: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/), but I'm not sure how to show certain text based on the OS.

I know I have to define Windows, Linux, Mac, etc. OS in CSS style sheet:

```
.win.chrome .example{
...
}
```

I am wondering how in the HTML I can show the different values for if windows, if linux, etc...

Comment: Clicking that URL gives me a "Security Warning" in Firefox under Windows. If that's caused by the browser-detection plugin, you might want to re-think using it.

Comment: @IMSoP Isn't this because of the Java execution (which is prompted up on chrome) ?

Comment: @RelevantUsername Java execution for what? Like I say, if this is part of the plugin, I would avoid it like the plague, as all your visitors will get this nasty popup asking if they trust your site.

Comment: Ah, never mind, the JS is just User-Agent sniffing. The author just has something else running on that page causing the security prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include all the variants in the HTML, then use the CSS selector to make them all `display: none` except the "correct" string, which you make `display: block` or `display: inline` as appropriate.

See [MDN docs on `display:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

**EDIT** The JS you linked to adds its classes to the root element of the document, i.e. `<html>`, so any rule beginning `html.win` will match only when the page is loaded in Windows. You then need to add classes to your own content which tell it which OSes *should* show that particular element. For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="win_only_block">You are running Windows!</div>
<div class="mac_only_block">You are running MacOS!</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Hide all the switchable blocks by default */
.win_only_block, .mac_only_block { display: none; }

/* Display the elements for the current OS (rule is more specific so will take precedence) */
html.win .win_only_block { display: block; }
html.mac .mac_only_block { display: block; }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I put display tags in css style, how do I select one in html?

Comment: @Yasir I've added an example to my answer showing how your HTML and CSS would relate to each other.

Answer (score 1):

I actually never used this css selector, but why don't you change the "display" style attribute value depending on the OS ?

```
.win .example {
  display:none;
}

.ie7 .example {
  display:block;
}
```

[...]

Answer (score 0):

Using the UA string to determine the OS is flawed, but if you don't care about that, fine. If you define an object with the different text strings you want, you can replace the content of the element with an appropriate string:

```
<script>
  function detectOS() {
    // use UA string to detect the OS, it will be wrong sometimes
    // return mac, win, linux, symbian, palm, ... unknown
  }

  function updateText(id) {
    var text = {
      mac: 'macs suck',
      win: 'windows blows',
      linux: 'linux loses',
      symbian: 'symbian rocks',
      ...
      unknown: 'damn…'
    }

    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var s = text[detectOS()];

    if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
      el.textContent = s;

    } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
      el.innerText = s;

    } else if (typeof el.innerHTML == 'string') {
      el.innerHTML = s;
    }
  }
</script>
```

And have a default string where the function fails. No need to define anything in a style sheet or include multiple redundant elements.

Comment: This requires you to mix the content in with the scripting logic, which is a bit ugly and not very extensible if you want to use this in multiple contexts, or dynamically change strings in question (e.g. i18n, editable in CMS, etc). Dynamically added CSS classes allow you to use HTML for content, and CSS effectively as a rules engine, with JS just providing the "glue".

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Placing an HTML element in the document for every OS that might be encountered knowing that only one will ever be displayed isn't very pretty to me. ;-)

Comment: Fair point. And you can never truly keep all your content in one place, because text is inevitably mixed in with complex markup and logic.